# SAS -. SQL format

Tags: sql, sas

I am importing a dollar value form xls via SAS to SQL

```
Imported value: 
$1878453.6
$1572177.4
```

format used in SAS:`%let format_out_response_n = dollar32.2;`

but I get this:

```
response_n 
18784.54
15721.77
```

I also tried: `%let format_in_response_nc = comma32.2;`
But here I get:

```
response_nc
1,878,454
1,572,177
```

So that is closer but still not right.
What should I use?

Comment: Show the code you are using to import from Excel.

Comment: Why would changing the values of macro variable have any impact on the format used to display an actual variable?  Please show how you used the value of that macro to generate actual SAS statements.

Comment: Hey, you need to show your SQL code. 
Proc SQL; 
Select 
varname format=dollar32.2
from Table 
;
Quit;